# Getting list of open Activities in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, soql

i have to retrieve list of OpenActivities related to a custom object Activities are enabled for custom object .for getting list i am using query like this

```
public List<OpenActivity> getActivity1(){

return [SELECT Subject from OpenActivities Where WhatId= :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') ];

}
```

when i save it it is giving me error

```
Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'OpenActivities' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 44 column 8
```

can any one please tell me how to retrieve list of open Activities in salesforce which is related to particular record object??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use query as it described here:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_openactivity.htm

e.g.

```
List<Account> a = [SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate,
                                  Description,
                                  Subject
                           FROM OpenActivities)
                   FROM Account];

 for (Account a: l) {
     System.debug(a.OpenActivities);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right answer is:

```
List<Account> a = [SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate,
                                  Description,
                                  Subject
                           FROM OpenActivities)
                   FROM Account];

 for (Account l: a) {
     System.debug(l.OpenActivities);
 }
```